# What is the html /css syntax - code to change a row color using calculated columns?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've seen examples ( same ones but in different places ) mostly using tasks as a basis and I've seen examples that only change the cell color background.

But how do you change the row color if a value of a column is "true" or if a choice values is either "A", "B" or "C"?

Tried using this, but it was a bit more complex than I needed it to be where "Color" was the column name and value...and somehow used a gif as well.
Couldn't figure it out.

```
="<DIV><IMG onload='GetSelectedElement(this,""TR"").style.backgroundColor="""&Color&"""' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' ></IMG></DIV>"
```

I'd be so grateful for your help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a detailed explanation for this IMG trick at http://www.ViewMaster365.com/#/How

CSR as mentioned below is the 'real' programmers solution.. but that only applies to SP2013, the IMG trick works in 2010 as well.. and can do much more

Comment: Hello Danny it seems it requires the purchase of ViewMaster?

Comment: No, just copy/paste the code from the site to color a row. The ViewMaster Tasks App does much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use **Client Side Rendering**

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        //your logic
        var isApproved = rows[i]["yourField"] == "someValue";
        if (isApproved)
        {
            var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
            var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
            //change the row color
            tr.style.backgroundColor = "#ada";
        }
    }
  }
});
```

Copy this code to a .js file and add the reference to this file to the *JSLink* property of the webpart that you want to customize with row colors.

The net is full of examples:
[Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)
[Introduction to Client-Side Rendering in SharePoint 2013](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/)
[SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)
[Highlight an entire row in a list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6ef86761-2536-4e7c-969d-fd32b053a547/highlight-an-entire-row-in-a-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: Hello nK and thank you.
I tried the last link, the one to the  code project page and followed through embedding a script editor web part. 
Testing it out with the footer example 

<script type = "text/javascript">
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({.......

But nothing shows up.

Am I missing a step?
Is there something ai need to do first?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Link the js script on tje jslink property of the web part

Comment: Nk, I am sorry but there is nothing from the code I used above taken from to color rows from "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views" that refers to any JS Links. What am I missing?

Comment: OK geeze, it was the noobie quotes !!

Comment: @MikeRooker updated my anwser